# Nginx 1.7.11 combined with PHP 5.6 in FPM mode

Tags: nginx, php

I've been trying to set up a nginx server version 1.7.11 with PHP 5.6 in FPM mode.  I cannot seem to get it to execute a script however.  It is constantly giving me

> "recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response
>   header from upstream"

I've tried countless variations in my php-fpm.conf file, my nginx.conf, my php5-fpm's www.conf, php.ini, etc.  When I run phpinfo() it all seems happy, but when I actually run a script it hangs and dies.

Does anyone have a set of configuration files they would be willing to share that actually works correctly?  I'm getting really frustrated and would appreciate any kind of assistance.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What does syslog say?

Comment: i'm struggling with a similar problem since yesterday (exact version), can you also share your fastcgi configuration as gist?

Comment: I run a tail -f syslog and what I see happen is:  Apr  7 20:59:57 ubuntu ps-watcher[1844]: php5-fpm stop/waiting#012php5-fpm start/running, process 40440

Answer (score 0):

I've made a while back a video tutorial configuring nginx with php-fpm on centos 6.5.

It describes the entire configuration to make it up and running.

Here is the URL:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psfF6p2fc4Y

Check also the video description for all details.

Comment: That was helpful, but I still am not getting it to work correctly.  I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's finally working.  Liviu's video was very helpful and helped me identify some issues to fix.  I also had ps-watcher looking for stalled PHP processes and restart them, which was causing more issues.  I took it out of the ps-watcher.conf file and the system stabilized significantly.  Here are my files, with minimal comments.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
# Basic Settings
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 20;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

# Gzip Settings
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain
                   text/css
                   application/json
                   application/x-javascript
                   text/xml
                   application/xml
                   application/xml+rss
                   text/javascript;

# Include files
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
upstream fpm-upstream {
  server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name  kurrle.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        allow 192.168.153.1;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass  fpm-upstream;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

```
[PHP]
display_errors On
display_startup_errors on
error_reporting E_ALL
log_errors On
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 17
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,

disable_classes =

zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
cli_server.color = On

[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
```

/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf:

```
pid = /run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10s
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:

```
[www]
user = nginx
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
pm = static
pm.max_children = 32
pm.max_requests = 200
pm.status_path = /status
chdir = /
catch_workers_output = yes
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M
```